# How to assign a Unique Group ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a challenging problem. I want to select some records from 1 table and find all related records from 2 other tables. When matched, I want to INSERT these records into a new table ORDER BY ID and Time. When inserted, I want to assign a Unique ID to all records with the same ID to represent the Group ID.

This I can do with a CTE. Here is the catch.

Each table is a specific record type. For the example, the first table is Entries, the second table is views and so forth.

These are log tables to an application beyond my control where I want to see the electronic path to a Entry by the same ID. But, I want to split the Group ID if the same ID has more than one Entry.

How can I do that in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Check out the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c30/20/0) I made that gives you a great example of one specific electronic path for one ID. In that example, I would want a Unique Group ID to be assigned and partition after the first Entry record as so:

```
GroupID ID      TIME                            TYPE
1001    3445    January, 01 2014 03:00:00+0000  View
1001    3445    January, 01 2014 04:00:00+0000  View
1001    3445    January, 01 2014 05:00:00+0000  View
1001    3445    January, 01 2014 06:00:00+0000  Click
1001    3445    January, 01 2014 07:00:00+0000  Entry
1002    3445    January, 01 2014 08:00:00+0000  View
1002    3445    January, 01 2014 09:00:00+0000  View
1002    3445    January, 01 2014 10:00:00+0000  View
1002    3445    January, 01 2014 11:00:00+0000  Click
1002    3445    January, 01 2014 12:00:00+0000  Entry
```

Thanks for any help you could provide. I'm still learning and this one was really being tricky with me, but maybe I'm just overlooking something that's staring me right in the face!

**NOTES**

- I think in order to make this work. I would have to find every Entry record that has the same ID. Then for each record, find the first Entry record before it's Datetime. When found, update that record with that Datetime so each record knows it's Datetime and the last Entry Datetime. That should make it easier to select the Click and Views between two dates and update each segment accordingly.
- Even better, I can go through each Click and View and find the Entry that's greater than it's current Datetime. Then select then MIN(Time) from that list and add that Datetime to each Click and View record. That way every Click and View has the same Datetime including the Entry where I can have a similarity to assign a Group ID!

Comment: What difference between `GroupID` 1001 and 1002? All rows seems to have same ID and same date...

Comment: Fabio: The difference is that 1001 is all records leading up to the first Entry record then 1002 is all other records after the first Entry record and leading up to the second Entry record. If there were 5 other Entry records with Clicks and Views between each one, then the ID would go up to 1003, 1004 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard to understand your problem,

but looking at the fiddle helped.

I hope I understood it correctly.

Try adding this to the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE temp1
    (
      id INT NOT NULL ,
      time DATETIME NOT NULL ,
      type CHAR(5) ,
      groupid INT
    );
```

Then execute this code:

```
 DELETE FROM temp1;
 INSERT INTO temp1
        SELECT  id ,
                time ,
                'Entry' ,
                0
        FROM    log1;
 INSERT INTO temp1
        SELECT  id ,
                time ,
                'View' ,
                0
        FROM    log2;
 INSERT INTO temp1
        SELECT  id ,
                time ,
                'Click' ,
                0
        FROM    log3;

 SELECT id ,
        time ,
        type ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
          FROM      temp1 AS B
          WHERE     B.type = 'Entry'
                    AND A.id = B.id
                    AND B.time < A.time
        ) AS groupid
 FROM   temp1 AS A
 ORDER BY id ,
        groupid ,
        time
```

[Here is my edit to your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bfb7/1/4).

Note: I am a DB2 programmer, with no specific SQL Server knowledge.

Comment: Here Unique ID based on quantity of previous `Entry`s. In case if GroupID will be stored in database permanently - It will work until previous entries will be deleted. Example: you have already `groupID` = 6(Next `groupID` must = 7). But if `Entry` with `groupID` = 3 deleted, then next `groupID` will be 6!(duplicate)

Comment: Good catch Fabio. In this case, each Group ID will be rebuilt in a new table as new records come in. Previous Group ID's shouldn't be deleted where a Group ID is duplicated. But, that's still a good mention!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Turophile. I'm going to test this in a few hours and let you know. It looks good and conformable to TSQL. *crosses fingers*

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a complete solution - just enough to show how to create the groups and give each group a unique id. I leave it for @Fastidious to adapt it to his needs.

Comment: Okies, I gave it a whirl. This suggestion works for me. The code selects the ID and Time. Then it orders by ID and Time. Being all Clicks and Views always become before a Entry, the code shows a clear path to every Entry record. The challenge was to Group multiple sets of Clicks, Views and Entries with an ID. This does that by counting those groups on the marker of Entry. In a table with thousands, the count always resets back to 0 with a new ID. But the point is, this adds a relation with each ID now starting with 0 and counting for each Entry under that same ID. I can now identify them!

Comment: Ran out of space. Just wanted to say thanks again. This is not the full solution, but a good stepping stone to the full solution. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @log1Id VARCHAR(25);
SET @log1Id='3445'
DECLARE  @temp TABLE
(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
groupid VARCHAR(25),
[time] datetime
);

INSERT INTO @temp (groupid,[time]) 
SELECT id, time FROM log2 WHERE id=@log1Id
UNION
SELECT id, time FROM log3 WHERE id=@log1Id
ORDER BY 1,2 desc

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

With reference to your fiddle.
Hope this helps you.